# Beautiful Soup question

Tags: python, regex, search, download, beautifulsoup

I've recently been recommended Beautiful Soup for a project in python. I've been reading the docs on the beautiful soup page but I can't make sense of it for what I want to do. I have a page that has a whole bunch of links. It's a directory with links, the file size etc. Lets say it looks like this:

```
Parent Directory/       -   Directory
game1.tar.gz    2010-May-24 06:51:39    8.2K    application/octet-stream
game2.tar.gz    2010-Jun-19 09:09:34    542.4K  application/octet-stream
game3.tar.gz    2011-Nov-13 11:53:01    5.5M    application/octet-stream
```

So what I want to do is supply a search string, lets say `game2` and I want it to download game2.tar.gz. I've had the idea to use RE's but I've heard Beautiful Soup is much better. Can anybody show and explain how I would do this?

Comment: What this question to do with BeautifulSoup. It's a HTML parser...what is the HTML part of your question!? What are you actually asking about???

Comment: ....The question says it all. I want to parse the HTML to get all the links, search for `game2` and download game2.tar.gz from that directory.

Comment: Use lxml instead of Beautiful Soup. It's more Beautiful.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is more beautiful

Comment: @Taha Jahangir Isn't there something still more powerful and more complicated than lxml ? That would be magnificent to use !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup  
import urllib2

def searchLinks(url, query_string):
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, convertEntities='html')
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        if a.has_key('href'):
            idx = a.contents[0].find(query_string)
            if idx is not None and idx > -1:
                yield a['href'] 

res = list(searchLinks('http://example.com', 'game2'))
print res
```

Comment: Hm, gives me an attribute error about 'list' has no attribute 'find'

Comment: i updated answer. `contetns` is a list. you may use `a.contetns[0]` or `a.string` instead. Anyway it's just a sketch

Comment: Ah I see. Is there any documentation for this type of thing? Could you also explain this a bit if you don't mind?

Comment: Official documentation: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html

Comment: @Andrey What is the value of url to try your code, please ? With ``url = 'http://pastie.org/1801547/'`` and **query_string** equal to **'game2'** , the result is ``[u'http://pastie.org/pastes/1801547/text', u'http://www.railsmachine.com']`` . There is nothing specific to **game2** in this result . By the way , I still haven't understood what the OP wants as a result.

Comment: ok, there is some peculiarity in `find` function (of python string object). sometimes when search fails it returns `None` instead of `-1`. i corrected condition checking. Thanks for pointing this out. As of `http://pastie.org/1801547`, it's example of html page source. OP wants to parse pages with such html code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear.

On the basis of the data you presented, I would think that you only need to do :

```
content = '''Parent Directory/       -   Directory
game1.tar.gz    2010-May-24 06:51:39    8.2K    application/octet-stream
game2.tar.gz    2010-Jun-19 09:09:34    542.4K  application/octet-stream
game3.tar.gz    2011-Nov-13 11:53:01    5.5M    application/octet-stream'''


def what_dir(x, content):
    for line in content.splitlines():
        if x in line.split(None,1)[0]:
            return line.split(None,1)[0]
```

.

### EDIT

Does this help you ? :

```
import urllib
import re

sock = urllib.urlopen('http://pastie.org/pastes/1801547/reply')
content = sock.read()
sock.close()

spa = re.search('<textarea class="pastebox".+?</textarea>',content,re.DOTALL).span()

regx = re.compile('href=&quot;(.+?)&quot;&gt;\\1&lt;')

print regx.findall(content,*spa)
```

### EDIT 2

Or is it what you want ? :

```
import urllib
import re

sock = urllib.urlopen('http://pastie.org/pastes/1801547/reply')
content = sock.read()
sock.close()

spa = re.search('<textarea class="pastebox".+?</textarea>',content,re.DOTALL).span()
regx = re.compile('href=&quot;(.+?)&quot;&gt;\\1&lt;')
dic = dict((name.split('.')[0],'http://pastie.org/pastes/1801547/'+name)
           for name in regx.findall(content,*spa))
print dic
```

result

```
{'game3': 'http://pastie.org/pastes/1801547/game3.tar.gz',
 'game2': 'http://pastie.org/pastes/1801547/game2.tar.gz',
 'game1': 'http://pastie.org/pastes/1801547/game1.tar.gz'}
```

Comment: No no no no, that is what the directory looks like on a web page. The actual html source looks like http://pastie.org/1801547

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of videos on YouTube about installing and using Beautiful Soup 4 to "scrape." They are quite detailed. I'm still going through them slowly, but the first one got me installed and running.
Search for "Beautiful Soup" on YouTube.

Comment: The Stack Overflow community prefers answers that directly answer a person's question by providing concrete examples of how to write code or a list of exact steps to help them troubleshoot an issue, etc. It is not helpful to just say search for related videos on YouTube. Anyone familiar with the web already knows how to do this.